# How to scope a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, backend, filterrific

I'm using [filterrific](https://rubygems.org/gems/filterrific/versions/2.0.5) gem, and need to scope the following.

I have 3 tables. And I would like scope the User model , that returns all university names.that all User belongs through Colleges. Colleges is the join table here. My models are as below (Rails 4.2):

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :colleges
     has_many :universities, :through => colleges

     # my current scope which is not working at all
     scope :user_university, -> (user_university){joins(colleges: [ {university: :name}]).where("universities.name = ? ", user_university)}
    end

    class Colleges < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :university
    end

    class University < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :colleges
     has_many :users, :through => colleges
    end
```

I keep getting errors and I'm unsure how to scope a model through a join table.

Answer (score 3):

Let try as this:

```
scope :user_university, -> (university_name) {
  joins(colleges: :university).where(universities: {name: university_name})
}
```

I rename the parameter `user_university` to `university_name` btw, `user_university` is kind of confusing!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!
Allright will rename it !